# generate different charts in the same activity using a spinner and achartEngine library

Tags: achartengine

I am a novice in android and I am using achartEngine library to draw line Graph. what I want to do is to update the graph by using a spinner. For exmaple, if I chose the first option I will get a yellow graph and when
I swich to the second option in my spinner, the graph changes and becomes white with new title and data

for the moment I can only update the data but not the rest of the graph

```
package com.example.test2;


import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.test2.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Graphique  extends Activity {


private GraphicalView mChart1;
private GraphicalView mChart2;


private TimeSeries glecimieSeries ;
private TimeSeries pressionSeries;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;

private XYSeriesRenderer glecimieRenderer;
private XYSeriesRenderer pressionRenderer;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer;

// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listeappareil;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_liste_appareil ;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String TAG_APPAREIL;
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NOM = "nom";
    private static final String TAG_J = "jour";
    private static final String TAG_Y = "Y";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray appareil = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graphique);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String pid = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
    String nom = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NOM);



    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblNom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nom_patient);
    lblNom.setText(nom);

    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mesure);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.appareils, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);    
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);



    OnItemSelectedListener selectedGraph = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                int position, long id) {
            String graph = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase();

            if(graph == "tensiometre"){
                url_liste_appareil = "http://10.0.2.2/connexion_android/"+graph+".php";
                TAG_APPAREIL = graph;
                // Setting up chart
                setupChart2();
                // Start plotting chart
                new ChartTask2().execute();     
        }else{

            url_liste_appareil = "http://10.0.2.2/connexion_android/"+graph+".php";
            TAG_APPAREIL = graph;
            // Setting up chart
            setupChart1();
            // Start plotting chart
            new ChartTask1().execute();

        }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

 // Setting ItemClick Handler for Spinner Widget
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectedGraph);


}

private void setupChart1(){     

    // Creating TimeSeries for Glecimie
    glecimieSeries = new TimeSeries("Glecimie");            

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Glecimie Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(glecimieSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize glecimieSeries    
    glecimieRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    glecimieRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    glecimieRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    glecimieRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    glecimieRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    glecimieRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);





    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();


    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);      

    // Adding glecimieRenderer and pressionRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(glecimieRenderer);


    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

        // Creating a Time Chart
        mChart1 = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");        

        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart1.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {                  
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries="Glecimie";
                if(seriesIndex==0)
                    selectedSeries = "Glecimie";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Pression";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value 
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                       getBaseContext(),
                       "Prélèvement au "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    chartContainer.removeAllViews();

        // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart1);




    }


    private class ChartTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Graphique.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_liste_appareil, "GET", param);

                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                        Log.d("Tous les appareil: ", json.toString());

            try{

                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    appareil = json.getJSONArray(TAG_APPAREIL);
                    Date[] dt = new Date[appareil.length()];


                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int j = 0; j < appareil.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject p = appareil.getJSONObject(j);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, j+1);
                        dt[j] = gc.getTime();


                        String y = p.getString(TAG_Y);
                        String jr = p.getString(TAG_J);

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date d = sdf.parse(jr);


                        // Adding data to Glecimie and Pression Series 

                        glecimieSeries.add(d,Double.parseDouble(y));

                        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Dates");
                        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Prélèvements");





                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // Plotting generated data in the graph


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into the graph
                     * */
                    mChart1.repaint();
                }
            });

        }

    } 


 private void setupChart2(){    



    // Creating TimeSeries for Pression
    pressionSeries = new TimeSeries("Pression");        

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();



    // Adding Glecimie Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(pressionSeries);      





    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize pressionSeries

    pressionRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    pressionRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    pressionRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    pressionRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    pressionRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    pressionRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();


    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);      

    // Adding glecimieRenderer and pressionRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same

    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(pressionRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

        // Creating a Time Chart
        mChart2 = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");        

        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart2.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {                  
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries="Glecimie";
                if(seriesIndex==0)
                    selectedSeries = "Glecimie";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Pression";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value 
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                       getBaseContext(),
                       " Prélèvement au"  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    chartContainer.removeAllViews();

        // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart2);




    }


    private class ChartTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Graphique.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_liste_appareil, "GET", param);

                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                        Log.d("Tous les appareil: ", json.toString());

            try{

                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    appareil = json.getJSONArray(TAG_APPAREIL);
                    Date[] dt = new Date[appareil.length()];


                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int j = 0; j < appareil.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject p = appareil.getJSONObject(j);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, j+1);
                        dt[j] = gc.getTime();


                        String y = p.getString(TAG_Y);
                        String jr = p.getString(TAG_J);

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date d = sdf.parse(jr);


                        // Adding data to Glecimie and Pression Series 


                        pressionSeries.add(d,Double.parseDouble(y));
                        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("la pression");
                        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Dates");
                        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Prélèvements");




                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // Plotting generated data in the graph


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into the graph
                     * */
                    mChart2.repaint();
                }
            });

        }

    } 


// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_graphique, menu);
            return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
        }
 }
```

Please help

Comment: How can I update the entire chart not only the data but also the color, title ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to refresh both charts, you need to call `repaint` on both:

```
mChart1.repaint();
mChart2.repaint();
```

Comment: I have a spinner with two options: "tensiometre" and "glocometre".what I want to do is to update the entire chart when I change the spinner's option from "tensiometre"  to "glucometre"(I want to update the title, the color, data ... etc) .
for the moment only data are updated, the chart keeps the old backround  and the old title

Comment: Just call setTitle, setBackground, setWhatever on your renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the color and other values of the chart by passing values.

In openChart() method you can pass the values.

```
private void openChart(final String[] code, final int[] distribution,final int color){      
defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(color);

}
```